# Creation of viewmodel for treeview in WPF with grouping of objects

Tags: c#

I am creating an application for chatting in WPF(C#.net).
I have created a class User with following attributes:
1.Company_name 
2.Branch 
3.Designation 
4.User_name 
I am getting the list of objects of class user.
I want to display the users in treeview as:

Company name1
      -Branch1
            -:Designation1
                  *User name1
                  *User name2
      -Branch2
            -:Designation1
                  *User name3
            -:Designation2
                  *User name4

when user list is refreshed, the tree structure will reloaded. 
I want to create this tree structure considering users with same parent. 
I am getting the user list at run time when a new user logs in.
 How to create such tree?
I want to know, how to create such treeview using "ViewModel and display it in WPF window"??

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough, I guess that your question is about how to create a hierarchy from a list of users by grouping on every property.

for that purpose you may use linq's grouping functionality. Here is a sample for the first level, you may repeat it in itself to create a hierarchy:

```
        var users = new[] { 
            new {
                CompanyName = "c1",
                Branch = "b1",
                Destination = "d1",
                UserName= "u1",
            },                new {
                CompanyName = "c1",
                Branch = "b1",
                Destination = "d1",
                UserName= "u1",
            },                new {
                CompanyName = "c1",
                Branch = "b1",
                Destination = "d1",
                UserName= "u1",
            },                new {
                CompanyName = "c2",
                Branch = "b1",
                Destination = "d2",
                UserName= "u2",
            },
        };

        var data = from u in users
                   group u by u.CompanyName into ug
                   select new { Node = ug.Key, Childs = ug };


        foreach (var i in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.Node);
            foreach (var node in i.Childs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + node.UserName);
            }
        }
```

And this is the code with the nested groupings:

```
        var users = new[] { 
            new {
                CompanyName = "c1",
                Branch = "b3",
                Destination = "d1",
                UserName= "u1",
            },                new {
                CompanyName = "c1",
                Branch = "b1",
                Destination = "d1",
                UserName= "u1",
            },                new {
                CompanyName = "c1",
                Branch = "b1",
                Destination = "d1",
                UserName= "u1",
            },                new {
                CompanyName = "c2",
                Branch = "b1",
                Destination = "d2",
                UserName= "u2",
            },
        };

        var data = from u1 in users
                   group u1 by u1.CompanyName into gByCompanyName
                   select new
                   {
                       Node = gByCompanyName.Key,
                       Childs = from u2 in gByCompanyName
                                group u2 by u2.Branch into gByBranch
                                select new
                                {
                                    Node = gByBranch.Key,
                                    Childs = from u3 in gByBranch
                                             group u3 by u3.Destination into gByDestination
                                             select new
                                             {
                                                 Node = gByDestination.Key,
                                                 Childs = from u4 in gByDestination
                                                          select new { Node = u4.UserName }
                                             }
                                }
                   };



        foreach (var n1 in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n1.Node);
            foreach (var n2 in n1.Childs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + n2.Node);

                foreach (var n3 in n2.Childs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + n3.Node);

                    foreach (var n4 in n3.Childs)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t" + n4.Node);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: i want to know, how to create such tree?

Comment: I updated the answer, if this is code produces the result you wanted, I have more notes about it to make it simpler.

Comment: Thank you, this code will surely help me, but i m creating the treeview in WPF.

Comment: i want to know, how to apply this code for creating ViewModel and treeview in WPF.